# Access enum name in Systemverilog

Tags: enums, system-verilog

I want to be able to retrieve the names for the types in an enumeration without having to actually assign a variable to them. Hence, given an enumeration like this

```sv
class my_class;
   typedef enum bit {
      ONE,
      TWO
   } fsm_state_t;
endclass
```

I know I can access the name of a declared variable like this:

```sv
class another_class;
...
my_class::fsm_state_t state = my_class::ONE;
   print(state.name());
...
endclass
```

Is it possible to access the names of the enum without actually having to declare and assign a variable? What I mean is something like this:

```sv
class another_class;
...
   print(my_class::ONE);
   print(my_class::TWO);
...
endclass
```

Comment: If you just want to convert a constant `myclass::ONE` to the string `"ONE"`, why not just say `print("ONE")`? (Alternatively, you can use macros to stringify the name)

Comment: if you use synopsys `VCS`, you can do `$display("%s")` for enum names. No one else implements this feature to the best of my knowledge. Otherwise, just create a table of enum names and get them by the value.

Comment: Well the print("ONE") works obviously but the point was to constrain it so that if someday the type is changed, the compiler notifies that the print must be changed as well. It is a consistency safety issue more than how do I print the name. Mark this as solved since the answer states there's no built-in methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, built-in methods cannot be called on types.

Answer (score 0):

> if someday the type is changed, the compiler notifies that the print
> must be changed as well.

By simply "using" the enumeration within your code, if it goes away you'll get a compile error. That seems to be what you're duplicating. A more *practical* duplication would be to value check every enum:

```
class another_class;
...
   if (my_class::ONE!=0) print("ONE has changed!");
   if (my_class::TWO!=1) print("TWO has changed!");
...
endclass
```

EDIT: or create a wrapper class for enums

```
virtual class enum_wrap#(type T);
  static function string name(T obj);
    return obj.name();
  endfunction
endclass

program testbench;
  initial begin
    typedef enum {ZERO, ONE, TWO, THREE} numbers_t;
    $display("ENUM without variable: %s", enum_wrap#(numbers_t)::name(THREE));
  end
endprogram
```

prints:

```
ENUM without variable: THREE
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I'm not quite sure whether I understand your first sentence 
_By simply "using" the enumeration within your code, if it goes away you'll get a compile error._
If I have a function that receives and integer and string, I want those to correspond to my_class:ONE and "ONE", the function does not know about the enum tho, so I could use `function(my_class::ONE, "TWO")` and therefore I won't be getting any compile error. I wanted to prevent that.

I marked the answer from Dave as the solution, and currently I'm not focusing on this

Comment: Then I suggest a virtual wrapper class. Edited answer